# XHR connection error with nextjs, don't know where it comes from

Tags: post, next.js, error-handling, axios, request

i'm making an app in nextjs with a post request using axios in the frontend and server-side i'm connected to mongoDb.
Here i post my frontend component:
**pages/produtcs/new.js**

```
import Product from "@/components/Product";

export default function NewProduct() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="sm:flex sm:items-center sm:justify-between py-3">
        <div className="text-center sm:text-left">
          <p className="mt-1.5 text-md text-gray-500 max-w-lg">
            Lets create a new product!
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr class="h-px border-0 bg-gray-300" />

      <div className="my-10">
        <Product />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

**@/components/Product.js**

```
import { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
export default function Product() {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
  const [price, setPrice] = useState("");
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
  async function craeteProject() {
    const data = {
      title,
      description,
      price,
    };
    await axios.post("/api/products", data);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={craeteProject} className="max-w-screen-sm mx-auto">
        <div class="mx-auto my-4">
          <div>
            <label
              htmlFor="example1"
              class="mb-1 block text-lg font-medium text-gray-700"
            >
              Title
            </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="example1"
              class="p-3 border block w-full rounded-md border-gray-300 shadow-sm focus:border-primary-400 focus:ring focus:ring-primary-200 focus:ring-opacity-50 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-gray-50 disabled:text-gray-500"
              placeholder="Product Title"
              value={title}
              onChange={(ev) => setTitle(ev.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mx-auto my-4">
          <div>
            <label
              htmlFor="example1"
              class="mb-1 block text-lg font-medium text-gray-700"
            >
              Select category
            </label>
            <select class="p-3 border block w-full rounded-md border-gray-300 shadow-sm focus:border-primary-400 focus:ring focus:ring-primary-200 focus:ring-opacity-50 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-gray-50 disabled:text-gray-500">
              <option value="">No category selected</option>
              <option value="">Option02</option>
              <option value="">Option03</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mx-auto my-4">
          <div class="mx-auto">
            <label
              htmlFor="example1"
              class="mb-1 block text-lg font-medium text-gray-700"
            >
              Images
            </label>
            <label class="flex w-full cursor-pointer appearance-none items-center justify-center rounded-md border-2 border-dashed border-gray-200 p-6 transition-all hover:border-primary-300">
              <div class="space-y-1 text-center">
                <div class="mx-auto inline-flex h-10 w-10 items-center justify-center rounded-full bg-gray-100">
                  <svg
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    fill="none"
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                    stroke-width="1.5"
                    stroke="currentColor"
                    class="h-6 w-6 text-gray-500"
                  >
                    <path
                      stroke-linecap="round"
                      stroke-linejoin="round"
                      d="M12 16.5V9.75m0 0l3 3m-3-3l-3 3M6.75 19.5a4.5 4.5 0 01-1.41-8.775 5.25 5.25 0 0110.233-2.33 3 3 0 013.758 3.848A3.752 3.752 0 0118 19.5H6.75z"
                    />
                  </svg>
                </div>
                <div class="text-gray-600">
                  <a
                    href="#"
                    class="font-medium text-primary-500 hover:text-primary-700"
                  >
                    Click to upload
                  </a>
                  or drag and drop
                </div>
                <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">
                  SVG, PNG, JPG or GIF (max. 800x400px)
                </p>
              </div>
              <input id="example5" type="file" class="sr-only" />
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mx-auto my-4">
          <div>
            <label
              for="example1"
              class="mb-1 block text-lg font-medium text-gray-700"
            >
              Description
            </label>
            <textarea
              rows={5}
              type="text"
              id="example1"
              class="p-3 border block w-full rounded-md border-gray-300 shadow-sm focus:border-primary-400 focus:ring focus:ring-primary-200 focus:ring-opacity-50 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-gray-50 disabled:text-gray-500 py-1"
              placeholder="Product Description"
              value={description}
              onChange={(ev) => setDescription(ev.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mx-auto my-4">
          <div>
            <label
              for="example1"
              class="mb-1 block text-lg font-medium text-gray-700 py-1"
            >
              Price
            </label>
            <input
              type="number"
              id="example1"
              class="p-3 border block w-full rounded-md border-gray-300 shadow-sm focus:border-primary-400 focus:ring focus:ring-primary-200 focus:ring-opacity-50 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-gray-50 disabled:text-gray-500"
              placeholder="Product Price"
              value={price}
              onChange={(ev) => setPrice(ev.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mx-auto my-4">
          <button
            className="w-full inline-block rounded border border-indigo-600 bg-indigo-600 px-12 py-3 text-sm font-medium text-white hover:bg-transparent hover:text-indigo-600 focus:outline-none focus:ring active:text-indigo-500"
            type="submit"
          >
            Save Product
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

**api/products.js**

```
import { mongooseConnect } from '@/lib/mongoose';
import { Product } from '@/models/Product';

export default async function handle(req, res) {
  const { method } = req;

  await mongooseConnect();

  if (method === 'POST') {
    const { title, description, price, images, category,details, brand, gender, sizes, colors } = req.body;

    const productDoc = await Product.create({
      title,
      description,
      price,
      images,
      category,
      details,
      brand, gender, sizes, colors
    })

    res.json(productDoc);
  }
```

The error it says due to XHR bad network, it has given me both error 500 and error 404, hope you know how to wake it work.